# Postfix MariaDB SSL Connection Error

Tags: mysql, postfix, ssl

I have two servers, both running Ubuntu 21.04.  I have Postfix (v3.5.6) installed on one server and MariaDB (v10.5.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) installed on the other.  When Postfix tries to connect to MariaDB it gets an "unsupported protocol" error:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[15106]: warning: connect to mysql server <name_of_db_server>: SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
postfix/trivial-rewrite[15106]: warning: virtual_alias_domains: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: table lookup problem
postfix/trivial-rewrite[15106]: warning: virtual_alias_domains lookup failure
postfix/trivial-rewrite[15106]: warning: virtual_alias_domains: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: table lookup problem
```

main.cf:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
```

mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf:

```
user = postfix
password = password
hosts = ip.address.of.db
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'
```

I can connect from the mariadb/mysql shell (mysql -u postfix -h dbserver -p) and it uses SSL/TLS.

I have seen lots of stuff that talks about lowering the TLS version on one machine or the other, but that isn't a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (albeit on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and with MariaDB 10.3.34 and Postfix 3.4.13) and spent the better part of two days getting to the bottom of it.

While the solution in your case is probably different, the contributing factors are probably the same.

Crucially, one must understand that Postfix connects to MySQL/MariaDB via the `libmysqlclient` library. That is, Postfix does not implement any of the connection details itself, so any problem like this tends to be with the settings applied to the MySQL client library *on the connecting machine*. I mention this specifically because it's entirely possible that you have a completely different MySQL client version/configuration installed on the connecting machine (the one on which Postfix is running) than you do on the MariaDB server itself. So, as you troubleshoot this, keep in mind that the relevant client-side settings will depend on what `mysql --version` produces on the *connecting* machine.

Of course, the MariaDB server's settings are also a factor, because it can force TLS or make it optional, and it can force specific TLS protocol versions.

In your specific case, I would try something like the following from the client (Postfix server) side:

```
mysql -upostfix -p -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --ssl --tls-version=TLSv1.0
```

(If the command fails with unsupported options or similar, then check the version with `mysql --version` and adapt them accordingly, per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/#options , or upgrade the MySQL client library to the same version as your MariaDB server version.)

This command both requires TLS  via `--ssl`, and specifies the TLS version via `--tls-version=TLSv1.0`.

If the connection fails, then increment the TLS version until it succeeds, by iterating through `--tls-version=TLSv1.1`, `--tls-version=TLSv1.2`, and `--tls-version=TLSv1.3`.

When the connection succeeds, that will determine the minimum TLS version that the MariaDB server requires, and that is the minimum version that the connecting (Postfix) machine must use when connecting. How you enforce that on the connecting machine depends entirely on the MySQL client library version (again, use `mysql --version` to check it). The relevant TLS-related options have changed over the last several major releases of both MySQL and MariaDB, so it's difficult to give more specific advice without knowing the MySQL client version. That said, the following resource has all of the relevant information for the latest versions of MariaDB (both client and server):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/secure-connections-overview/

Assuming you are running the same MariaDB *client* version on the Postfix machine that you're running for the MariaDB server, then the above resource includes verbatim examples that should work for you:

On the MariaDB *server*:

```
[mariadb]
tls_version = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

On the MySQL/MariaDB client (the Postfix server):

```
[client-mariadb]
tls_version = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

If you haven't resolved this already, feel free to add comments/questions and I will gladly update this post with information more specific to your situation.